# do i have to do something to have the schedule run automatically every minute?

Tags: php, laravel

I created this function but it only works once when I execute this command:

`php artisan schedule: run`

Should I have to do something to continue automatic? is it then triggered automatically when you enter the site only once and run it alone?

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
  {
        $schedule->call(function () {
              $dias1 = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(5);
              $dias2 = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(15);
              $encomendasnaopagas = encomendas::where('estado', 1)->where('updated_at', '<', $dias1)
                    ->join('distritos', 'encomendas.distrito', '=', 'distritos.id')
                    ->update(['estado' => 5]);
    
              $encomendasenviadas = encomendas::where('estado', 3)->where('updated_at', '<', $dias2)
                    ->join('distritos', 'encomendas.distrito', '=', 'distritos.id')
                    ->update(['estado' => 4]);

        })->everyMinute();
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction "Starting the Scheduler"

Comment: I've seen the documentation and I still don't understand why ..

Comment: don't understand why what? which part do you not understand? it tells you how to have it run every minute ... do you not know what cron is perhaps? or how to add a cron job? need to know what you don't understand to clarify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be something you have missed in the documentation on keeping the scheduler running

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#defining-schedules

> When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to your server, consider using a service such as Laravel Forge which can manage the Cron entries for you:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

You will need to setup an entry in your `crontab` or similar cron management system.